# Add MahApps.Metro Context Menu programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, mahapps.metro, programmatically-created

since I am loading dynamic content into a `StackPanel` I would like to add a `ContextMenu` on each Object.

Right now I am doing it with `System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu` and it's working.

Unfortunately the Menu looks like in an old Window form and not like the nice Menu of MahApps.

On the Internet page can I find the documentation how to add a menue in xaml, but not how to create a Menu via code.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking up in `MahApps.Metro` I found that ContextMenu's `Style` has the Key `MetroContextMenu`.

So you just can create your normal ContextMenu in CodeBehind. The you could add the following `Style` to your `App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--  MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive!  -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.ContextMenu.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!--  Accent and AppTheme setting  -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Green.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- Apply MetroStyle for ContextMenu to ContextMenus in Application scope -->
    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroContextMenu}" />
</Application.Resources>
```

It is only the you have to apply to your `ContextMenu`. There is no special `ContextMenu` control provided by MahApps (it is only the `Style`!).